# Cannot mock partial Log facade in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, testing, mocking

I'm trying to mock laravel `Log`. This is my code:

```
public function test_process_verify_card()
{
    Log::shouldReceive('error')->once();
    Log::makePartial();
    $class = new MyClass();
    $class->myFunction();
}
```

This is `MyClass` look like:

```
class MyClass
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->logger = Logg::channel('test');
    }

    public function myFunction()
    {
        // ... some logic
        $this->loggger->error('Errror!!');
    }
}
```

When I run test this test case, it throw error

```
Call to a member function runningUnitTests() on null

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php:568
```

I tried to debug this error by putting `dd()` in `LogManager` class

```
    protected function parseDriver($driver)
    {
        $driver ??= $this->getDefaultDriver();
        dd($this->app); // <--- This is my code
        if ($this->app->runningUnitTests()) {
            $driver ??= 'null';
        }

        return $driver;
    }
```

But it show that `$this->app` is not `null`.

I've tried mock facade `Date` before and it works fine.

I want to test that `myFunction` executes logging action. Is this correct way to do it?

#### Update

I also tried to mock it through `partialMock()` function:

```
    public function test_process_verify_card()
    {
        $this->partialMock(Logger::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('error')->once();
        });
        $class = new MyClass();
        $class->myFunction();
    }
```

But it still not works, it shows error:

```
  Method error(<Any Arguments>) from Mockery_0_Illuminate_Log_Logger should be called
 exactly 1 times but called 0 times.

  at vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit:98
```

Comment: You're making it very hard to differentiate between typos in your code and typos in the code you are sharing here. For example where you say "your code" `dd($this->app())` there should be no `()` next to `app` and there should be a semi-colon in the end as well. There's no way to know whether your issues are due to things like this or if this is just sloppy question writing. And sidenote, `Log` never receives `error` here, it only ever receives `channel` which would return a logger instance

Comment: @apokryfos Sorry for typos, i've updated my question, but I'm sure that problem is not come from my typos, the problem come first, then I added these line after. And with your sidenote, do you have any suggestion for mocking `Log` facade in this case ?

Comment: I guess something like `Log::shouldReceive('channel')->andReturn($this->partialMock(Logger::class, ..))` and in what is returned from `channel` you can mock an instance of a logger

Comment: I just had a similar idea, but instead of using facade mock, I used test class mock `$this->mock(LogManager::class, function (MockInterface $mock) use ($logMock) {
$mock->shouldReceive('channel')->andReturn($logMock);})`. With `$logMock` mock to `Logger` class. But it doesn't work, I wonder why?

Comment: You are using the log manager through its facade so you need to mock it through its facade as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would believe the problem why this is not working, is as `Log::channel` returns a channel on the partial mock. Therefor the mocked instance never receive the error call.

In `Mockery` you can easily do chained calls, by using '->' in the `shouldReceive()` call.

```
Log::shouldReceive('channel->error')
    ->once()
    ->andReturn(null);
```

Comment: It worked and very simple. Thanks

Comment: doesn't work for me, am i missing something? `Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException: Method info(<Any Arguments>) from Mockery_2__demeter_5611dc036b72b80948c69b1a31056a3b_channel should be called
 exactly 1 times but called 0 times.`

Comment: Hmm how do you call the log method?

Comment: This is excellent, just what I was looking for!